# How can I hide missing or null bars in a Chart.js bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to display data from multiple datasets, with some datasets not having data for a specific x value. I'm using chart.js version 4.3.0.

To achieve this, I'm using a (x;y) data structure as described here: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html#object

However I'm facing weird and inconsistent behavior.

I have tried reproducing the issue with a minimal example :

```js
const data = [
    { year: 2010, count: 10 },
    { year: 2013, count: 15 },
    { year: 2110, count: null },
    { year: 5464, count: 4 },
];


const data2 = [
    { year: 564, count: 30 },
    { year: 2010, count: null },
    { year: 2110, count: 3 },
    { year: 5464, count: 3 },
];

new Chart(
    document.getElementById('acquisitions'),
    {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Set 1',
                    data: data.map(row => ({ x: row.year, y: row.count })),
                    backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Set 2',
                    data: data2.map(row => ({ x: row.year, y: row.count })),
                    backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
                },
            ],
            xLabels: Array.from(new Set([...data, ...data2].map(row => row.year))).sort((a, b) => a-b)
        },
        options: {
            skipNull: true,
            responsive: true
        }
    }
);
```

Here is the produced chart :

[image: resulting bar chart]

The behavior I want is what is happening for the **2013** and **2110** columns : there is only one column, and no empty space.

I don't understand what is happening for the **564** and **2010** columns though !

- The **2010** and **2110** rows are configured in the same way : both are present in both datasets, one having a value, the other having null.
- The **564** and **2013** rows are also similar : they are only present in one dataset.

However I'm seeing different behavior !

Am I doing something wrong ? Is this a bug ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I have tried adding

```js
const data = [
    { year: 2010, count: 10 },
    { year: 2013, count: 15 },
    { year: 2110, count: null },
    { year: 5464, count: 4 },
    { year: 564, count: 3 },    // new row
];
```

And the chart looks broken :
[image: broken chart]

Comment: Why you think that 2013 is correct. It is only present in set 1. Ideally this should not show set 2.

Comment: @CodeThing I don't get what you mean. There is only one green column for 2013, so it's good since it is only in set 1 as you mentioned

Comment: Ya. My bad. I just realised. This seems to be an issue with library as it is behaving differently if we switch null to value between datasets.

Comment: @MarcF did  my answer solve your question? If so please consider  ccepting my answer with the green checkmark.

Comment: @winner_joiner Yes the workaround seems to work. I still opened an issue since this seems to be a bug. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply can fix all issues, if you sort the data sets ([array sort function documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) ), on the `year` property.
Since *"misalignment"* causes issues, of the datasets.

**Here a demo:**

```js
const data = [
    { year: 2010, count: 10 },
    { year: 2013, count: 15 },
    { year: 2110, count: null },
    { year: 5464, count: 4 },
    { year: 564, count: 3 }, 
];

const data2 = [
    { year: 564, count: 30 },
    { year: 2010, count: null },
    { year: 2110, count: 3 },
    { year: 5464, count: 3 },
];

let years =  [ ...data.map( x => x.year), ...data2.map( x => x.year)];

years.forEach((year) => {
    if(!data.find( x => x.year == year)){
        data.push({ year })
    }
    if(!data2.find( x => x.year == year)){
        data2.push({ year })
    }
});

data.sort((a,b) => a.year - b.year);
data2.sort((a,b) => a.year - b.year);

const config =  {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Set 1',
                    data: data.map(row => ({ x: row.year, y: row.count })),
                    backgroundColor: '#00ff00'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Set 2',
                    data: data2.map(row => ({ x: row.year, y: row.count })),
                    backgroundColor: '#ff0000'
                },
            ],
            xLabels: Array.from(new Set([...data, ...data2].map(row => row.year))).sort((a, b) => a-b)
        },
        options: {
            skipNull: true,
            responsive: true
        }
    };

new Chart(
    document.getElementById('chart'),
    config
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>  

<div class="chart" style="height:184px; width:350px;">
    <canvas  id="chart" ></canvas>
</div>
```

**Update:** You just need to match the Dataset entries, of both dataset.

In the example above I do it with looping through all year of both dataset and add the missing once in the respective array. *There is probably a more efficient way, but I just wanted to showcase the reason for the problem, and a solution.*

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue though, does it ? I still see empty spaces in the "2013" and "2110" columns (the columns occupy half the space available, although they should occupy the full width). Also, there should be two bars for 5464, they overlap in your sample. is it safe to assume it's a library bug ?

Comment: @MarcF sorry I just focused on one part of the problem, I updated the example to fix the whole thing.